# Azure Table Storage - Property Attributes?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I trying out Azure Table Storage and as an example are here a sample entry Model

```
public class MyEntity : TableEntity
{
    public string MyStringProperty { get; set; }

    public int MyIntProperty { get; set; }

    [IgnoreProperty]
    public int MySpecialProperty { get; set; }
}
```

The sample use the [IgnoreProperty] provided by the framework **but can it really be true that you can't decorate the rest of the Properties with a [Name("")] Attribute or similar** so the code is refactor-safe?. I've tried to use dataMember, JsonProperty but nothing seems to be picked up by the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table Storage SDK only offers two attributes [IgnoreProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.ignorepropertyattribute?view=azure-dotnet) and [EncryptProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.encryptpropertyattribute?view=azure-dotnet)(this property only available in .Net Framework). Like what you have found, attributes come from other SDK are not honored.

It's reasonable to say table entity is designed not to work with other attributes so that everything is under control strictly. We can overwrite method of [TableEntity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableentity?view=azure-dotnet#methods) to read and write entity based on our requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, but damn that is poor half-finished design :-(